# Publish iPhone app on apple store without our developer name

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to publish my free app on the apple Store for iPhones.

But I don't want my real name to be shown on the store and i don't have a company.
Is there a way without risks to publish my app without showing my real name on the store ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: There once was a time when a developer could decide which name be shown in public; you could use a pseudonym back then. Is that no longer an option upon registration?

Comment: Hi, Thanks ! And ups, sorry. I removed the "iphone" tag.  It seems like the "public name" you are talking about isn't available anymore at registration..

Comment: I think I remember it being asked of you on your first app submit. Do you have the registration for your private account completed?

Comment: @JanGreve this is definitely the best option if you are not a company, however your real name will still appear as the seller in the app description.

Comment: @Bamsworld yeah, there may be no way to disguise oneself completely, for legal reasons probably:)

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 2):

The following is from [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html)

> Note: The company name defaults to the legal entity name you enter when you enroll in the Apple Developer Program. If you enroll as a company, you can set the company name (distinct from your legal entity name) only once when you add your first app, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App. The company name must be a registered DBA or trade name. The company name will be used for all your apps and can’t be changed later. If you enroll as an individual, the company name is the same as your legal name. In the store, the “company name” is used prominently for navigation and to group your apps. Your legal entity name appears as the “seller” of your apps. For example, “Apple” is the company name and “Apple, Inc” is the seller name. When users tap your company name, they see all of the apps you have on the store

Please note that the legal entities name is always displayed as the seller in any app description as mentioned above, meaning **if you are not a legally registered company your real name is displayed as the seller**.

Answer (score 0):

For the iOS App store, you have to form a corporation and enroll using that corporations legal name if you don't want to use your own personal legal name.

Even if/when the app store allowed entering an "artists name", it still showed the developer's legal name in other places in the store, so that didn't not show your name.

Comment: I will probably register a DBA name because it seems that there is no other solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A DBA won't work.  Apple only accepts incorporated entities with a D&B number.